# How do I get minimum and maximum epoch time from python dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, max, min, epoch

I'm having one python dictionary. In this dictionary I saved value as a epoch times. I want to know which is maximum epoch time and which is minimum epoch time, Further I want to split those epoch times into different time-slots.

**Program-Code-**

```
for key,value in self.key_dict.iteritems():
        print 'key : ' + str(key) + ' value : ' + str(value)
```

**Output-**

```
key : 1 value : 1468332422164000
key : 2 value : 1468332421672000
key : 3 value : 1468332423489000
key : 4 value : 1468332423568000
key : 5 value : 1468332421383000
key : 6 value : 1468332421818000
key : 7 value : 1468332423490000
key : 8 value : 1468332421195000
key : 9 value : 1468332421098000
```

**Further divide into different time slots -**

It means I just want to plot x-axis using this times. For that purpose I'm finding min and max times. Depend on difference between minimum and maximum time-slots  I want to split it in 3 or 4 time-slots maximum. example - 1468332421098000 to 1468332423490000.

These are the epoch times as a value of the dictionary. how I can find maximum and minimum from that and further divide into different time-slots for the plotting of the x-axis of the graph?

Comment: Can you explain about the time slots specifics

Comment: Further divide into different time-slots?

Comment: @Jossie Calderon- see my edit.

Comment: @kit What module will you use to plot it?

Comment: @Jossie Calderon- Not using any module I just want to plot one graph on the console.

Comment: @kit I've never done that before. Can you show me? I use plot.ly for my graphs.

Comment: @Jossie Calderon- [ https://github.com/LucaCanali/PyLatencyMap ]  refer this for console based heatmap.

Answer (score 0):

Max and min can be determined using functions `min()` and `max()` on `dict.values()` which returns a list of the dictionary's values:

```
minimum = min(self.key_dict.values())
maximum = max(self.key_dict.values())
```

Comment: @mhawke- This is not a complete answer. What should I do for spiting whole dictionary values in the 3 to 4 slots?

Comment: @kit: To be fair it's not a complete question, and I can't read minds :) Can you make clear what you mean by time-slots and where does the 3 to 4 slots come into it? Do you mean to group the values in some way?

Comment: @mhawke- sorry for not providing proper explanation. see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

In case you want both the key and the value to be returned, use `min` and `max` function, together with the `key` kwarg:

```
key_dict = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}

print min(key_dict.iteritems(), key=lambda item: item[1])
# ('a', 1)
print max(key_dict.iteritems(), key=lambda item: item[1])
# ('b', 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to `numpy`, then you can use it to help you bin the data.  First, lets compute the minimum and maximum of our values.

```
mn = min(self.key_dict.values())
mx = max(self.key_dict.values())
```

Now create some bins for plotting that equally divide these:

```
# five equally spaced points delimiting four bins
bins = numpy.linspace(mn, mx, num=5)
```

Now find the bin each value is in:

```
values = numpy.array(list(self.key_dict.values())
bin_numbers = numpy.digitize(values, bins)
```

What you want to plot from there is unclear from your question.  You may be wanting to plot `bin_numbers` versus your dictionary keys ... if you wish to plot a histogram, then it would easier to use `numpy.histogram` rather than `numpy.digitize`.

Comment: @kit If you simply wish to know the boundaries of your time slots, they are in the `bins` array in this example.

Comment: @donkopotamus- bins contains time-slots but this time-stamps are in different formats how I can get my epoch again?